# How to Validate year with regex validation in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

in Laravel application I need save year input data, it is should be numeric number and should include only 4 numbers. this is current system,

```
'year'    => 'required|min:4|numeric',
```

this is working but can enter more than 4 numbers. how can enter only 4 numbers here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value:

```
'year' => 'required|integer|min:1900|max:2018'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
'year' => 'required|digits:4|integer|min:1900|max:'.(date('Y')+1),
```

the +1 is to account for a new year registration in Australia for example. You don't want to accidentally cut them off because they are ahead. Or, maybe more precise, use \Carbon\Carbon::tomorrow()->year

Answer (score 1):

```
'year' => 'required|digits:4'
```

Try this one too